# iOS range to detect beacons with predefined proximity UDID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ibeacon

I am working on app which used to detect beacons in iOS device using objective c. I have successfully done the scanning of beacons using core bluetooth and core location framework i.e did range beacons which provides an array of scanned beacons.

Case - I have to discard beacon scanned which are of distance more than 10 meters. So I have used RSSI value for that and calculated distance using formula and not considering beacons above that distance.

Problem - did range beacon is not providing the beacons distance more than 5-6 meters sometimes it provide around 8 meter beacon also.

Question - is there any specific range after that iOS discard the scanned beacons automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It is not unusual for mobile devices to not be able to detect beacons beyond 8-10 meters. This has nothing to do with the operating  system and is caused by the radio signal level falling below the noise floor as detected by the receiver.

The maximum distance a beacon can be detected is typically 40-50 meters in ideal clear line of sight conditions, but this also relies on the bluetooth transmitter being set to the maximum radio signal level allowed by international regulations, and the transmitter's antenna being directed generally toward the receiver.

It also relies on the receiving mobile device having it's antenna oriented toward the beacon transmitter and not blocked by a case or other radio obstruction.

Typically conditions you describe are caused by a beacon transmitting a signal far weaker than allowed by law.  This may be adjusted on some models.  Check the instructions from the beacon manufacturer.

Some mobile device.models have poor Bluetooth receiver antennas, although Apple devices are generally good. (Huawei Android devices are notoriously poor receivers.). If in doubt, try another device.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I conducted a test in an open park with two of android device and two of iOS device (iPhone5s , iPhone 6). But both of iOS devices were not able to scan beacon beyond 8 meters whereas both of android devices were able to scan those  any though why it is so?

Comment: It may simply be that the Android devices have a better receiving antenna.  If you look at the raw RSSI (a measurement of signal strength with less negative values indicating a relatively stronger signal) for the detection, you will probably notice that at the same distance (say 5 meters) the iOS device detects a weaker RSSI (perhaps -90 dB) and the Android device detects a stronger RSSI (perhaps -70dB).  Devices typically cannot detect beacon signals at much less than -100 to -110 dBm.

Comment: As per all theories Apple devices are far better receivers than others devices. is there any way to achieve more accuracy and distance scanning.